# Incorporating the Settings API in WordPress Themes - by Chip Bennet

Tags: options, settings-api

I am using the code by Chip Bennett to create a settings options page for my plugin. The problem is that I am getting a Warning error as indicated below that I cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

> Warning: call_user_func(ch_settings_defaults_style_section_text)
>   [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid
>   callback in
>   /home/loc123/public_html/domaindvb.com/wp-admin/includes/template.php
>   on line 1083

```
    <?php
function ch_admin_options_page() {
    global $pagenow;
 ?>
    <div class="wrap">
<?php
        /* Calls function to add tabs */
        ch_admin_options_page_tabs ();

        /* adds the "updated" admin notice */
        if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
            echo "<div class='updated'><p>Custom Header settings updated successfully.</p></div>";
        }
?>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">   
            <?php
            settings_fields('mycustom_options');
            do_settings_sections('mycustom');
            ?>
        <?php
        if ( 'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'ch-settings' == $_GET['page'] ) :
             if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) ) :
                  $tab = $_GET['tab'];
             else:
                  $tab = 'general';
             endif;
             switch ( $tab ) :
                  case 'general' :
                require ('options-register-defaults.php') ; 
                break;
                  case 'Home Page' :
                require( 'options-register-homepage.php' );
                break;
             endswitch;
        endif; 
         ?>
        <p></br></p>

        <input name="mycustom_options[submit-<?php echo $tab; ?>]" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Settings', 'default'); ?>" />

        <?php /* Add a Reset Button */ ?>
        <input name="mycustom_options[reset-<?php echo $tab; ?>]" type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset Defaults', 'default'); ?>" />

        </form>

    </div>
<?php
}
?>

<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'chr_settings');
function chr_settings() {

    /*  register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback )- Associates an option group passed to settings_fields with database entry */
    register_setting( 'mycustom_options', 'mycustom_options', 'ch_options_validate' ); 
    add_settings_section('ch_settings_defaults_style', 'Style Options', 'ch_settings_defaults_style_section_text', 'mycustom');

}
?>
```

**File:** `options-register-defaults.php`

```
<?php
function ch_settings_defaults_style_section_text() { ?>

     <p><?php _e( 'Manage Header options for the Oenology Theme. Refer to the contextual help screen for descriptions and help regarding each theme option.', 'mycustom' ); ?></p>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: So where and when is the `options-register-defaults.php` included?

Answer (score 0):

You should include your `options-register-defaults.php` to make the callback available.

```
function chr_settings() {

require_once 'options-register-defaults.php'; // add path to file

    /*  register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback )- Associates an option group passed to settings_fields with database entry */
    register_setting( 'mycustom_options', 'mycustom_options', 'ch_options_validate' ); 
    add_settings_section('ch_settings_defaults_style', 'Style Options', 'ch_settings_defaults_style_section_text', 'mycustom');

}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try changing the location where it is included.